# Find unused masterpages

Tags: 2007, master-page, custom-masterpage

Were in the process of cleaning up some old solutions and as such deleting old page layouts & master pages.

We're on SharePoint 2007.
I've been able to use the master page gallery to show related resources and see which page layouts aren't being used but I'm now trying to find which master pages aren't used. When i look at these none of them appear to be used by any other page but I know that some are.

Any ideas how I can go about finding which master pages are no longer in use? or the opposite - find which master pages are in use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to find list of master pages currently used by the sites in site collection of web app. Try using below PowerShell commend let.

```
Get-SPWebApplication | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select Title, URL, MasterUrl  |  Ft -autosize -wrap > D:\mysite.txt
```

In the output generated file you should see MasterUrl that would give you the URL of master page applied for that site..

Comment: any thoughts on how to do this for all site though? not really familiar with powershell